# Working with stored procedure in LINQ?

Tags: stored-procedures, linq-to-sql

In web application, I am using LINQ to call a procedure, the procedure is parameter procedure. but when I am passing arguments it is giving errors, This is my code:

```
 MyLinqsDataContext DataContext=new MyLinqsDataContext ();
        int eno=Convert.ToInt32 (txtempno.Text );
        int dep=Convert .ToInt32 (txtDep.Text );
        var sqr = from qr in DataContext.USP_Insert_Emp(eno, txtName.Text, dep) 
      select qr;
```

But is giving error like:

> Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source  type `int`.  `Select` not found.

This is my Proc :

```
create procedure USP_Insert_Emp(@empid int,@ename varchar(60),@deptid int)
as
 begin
  insert into Emp (empid ,ename,deptid ) values (@empid ,@ename ,@deptid)
 end
```

Comment: Seems like you are passing parameters of wrong type to your stored procedure. Can you please post your stored procedure source code?

Comment: Thank you for reply Hoang Huynh, i place my proc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataContext.USP_Insert_Emp` returns an `int`.

The error you are getting is because you are trying to call `Select` on an `int` and not an `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: Thank you Leppie, so what i have to change in my code. i am new to  linq. can you help me for solving the problem

Comment: `int r = DataContext.USP_Insert_Emp(eno, txtName.Text, dep);`

Comment: Thank you Mr. Leppie it is working fine, very help ful for me , can you give me any rerence to study the linq.